# Finding first multiple of 5 for a value in my program

Tags: objective-c, math

I can't figure out how to do something very simple in my program.

Given a float value `f` (it could be 0, or it could be 5 million, etc), I need to find the first value `x` such `x >= f` (x is greater than f) and `x` is a multiple of 5.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976832/what-does-the-double-do-in-ceildouble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide by 5, round up to the next integer (using `ceil()` or similar), multiply by 5 again.

Comment: can you show me how to use ceil? This is an Objective-C program.

Comment: Objective C is still C, you have access to `<math.h>`.

Comment: @reising: `ceil(3.5)` yields 4.

Answer (score 0):

You can use modulo operator and do something like:

```
x = f - f % 5 + 5
```

Comment: f is float, and even truncated to int then it will break for multiples of 5.